# Adding class to Game

Tags: c#, monogame

I work on a little project, and in the past, I used `SpriteManager : DrawableGameComponent` as my `SpriteManager` class.

I have been told that `DrawableGameComponent` is not so recommended to use, so I decided to make my own custom methods in a new class called `SpriteManagerGeneral`. Now I try to acces that class via `Game`. In the past I used this in `Game`:

```
spriteManager = new SpriteManager(this);
Components.Add(spriteManager);
```

But now I can't do this with `SpriteManagerGeneral` because it's not a `GameComponent`.

Do I just change my class (and edit my methods) to `SpriteManagerGeneral : GameComponent` or is there another way (that is better than `GameComponent`) to do this?

NOTE: I'm a beginner in programming.

NOTE2: Yes I know why `DrawableGameComponent` is not so recommended.

Comment: "I have been told that DrawableGameComponent is not so recommended to use" Did you understand *why*, so you aren't replacing it with an even worse solution? What exactly does your `SpriteManagerGeneral` do and how are other parts of your application interacting with it?

Comment: All you have to do is create a class without deriving it from GameComponent, or DrawableGameComponent.  Incorporate your own Draw and Update methods, and call them.  And instead of using Components.Add()  you would simply create a reference, in you Game class,  SpriteManager.

Comment: @Philipp Yes I understand why. My `SpriteManagerGeneral` does exactly the same BUT it has another name because I keep the other Spritemanager class if something goes wrong. My class is used to handle all the sprites.

Comment: @Jelle So what you are *actually* asking is how to write a class which is a valid `GameComponent`?

Comment: No, my question actually was how to use my `SpriteManager` class (wich is not derived from anything) in `Game`. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @Philipp forgot to add @ to the comment above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your SpriteManager class would not derive from anything.
You would write in your own Update and Draw functions:

```
public class SpriteManager 
{
    GraphicsDevice GraphicsDevice;

    public SpriteManager(GraphicsDevice graphicsDevice)
    {
        GraphicsDevice = graphicsDevice;
        LoadContent();
    }

    private void LoadContent()
    {
        //Use GraphicsDevice to load content here
    }

    public void Update(GameTime gametime)
    {
         float elapsed = (float)gametime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;
    }

    public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {
         spriteBatch.Draw(foo);
    }
}
```

Don't forget to call Update() in your Update, and Draw() in your Draw from the main Game class:

```
...

SpriteBatch SpriteBatch;
SpriteManager SpriteManager;

protected override void LoadContent()
{
     SpriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);
     SpriteManager = new SpriteManager(GraphicsDevice);
}

protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
    SpriteManager.Update(gameTime);
}

protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
{
    SpriteBatch.Begin();
    SpriteManager.Draw(SpriteBatch);
    SpriteBatch.End();
}

...
```

Comment: What do you mean by "main gameloop". Do you mean the `Game` class?

Comment: Yes. The main game class. I will revise in a bit, I'm out drinking at the moment.

Comment: Ok, you are really helpfull on my questions! I will try this as soon as I can.